# How do I write a function that can be called if it exists, but doesn't throw an error (and gets ignored) if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an abstract class called Component. Component has three functions: Start(), Update(float timeStep) and Draw().
I don't want every class that inherits Component to use all three of the functions however.

I could of course write all functions out (EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION: as overwrite functions, while the base functions are virtual) with nothing but return statements in them, but I think that's very inconvenient to do for every class that inherits Component. Plus, I've seen it done the way I want elsewhere.

For instance, in Unity, it's possible to omit the Update and Start functions completely in classes that inherit MonoBehaviour without any problems! The function will just be ignored by Unity if it can't find it.

How do I do this for myself? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though I wasn't aware of the existence of partial methods, and it does have some semblance of what I'm trying to achieve, I think it's not what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to divide one class into two, I'm trying to get this kind of behaviour with inherited classes.

Comment: You can decompile Unity to see how it's done, or perhaps look here (https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled). But, I don't think its worth the effort.

Comment: @Tom Well, MonoBehaviour [does not appear](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/MonoBehaviour.cs) to contain any definitions of such methods, but e.g. [`UIBehaviour` does](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystems/UIBehaviour.cs) in a way that implies they are declared there, not in MonoBehaviour, and yet the comments in `UIBehaviour` tell you to "see MonoBehaviour.Awake" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand two keywords for the solution:

1. `Virtual` : **It can be overridden but not necessary.**
2. `abstract` : **Must be overridden.**

Take look at this example code for better understanding.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void MustOverride(); // It must be overriden

    public void NoNeedOverride()
    { 
        // logic goes here
    }   // No need to override

    public virtual void CanBeOverride()
    {
        // logic goes here
    }   // Not necessarily be overriden
}

public class DerivedClass : Base
{
}
```

Comment: *"I could of course write all functions out with nothing but return statements in them, but I think that's very inconvenient"*

Comment: One thing that confuses me here, is that the virtual keyword forces the inheriting class to use the overwrite keyword. This is something that isn't seen in Unity's MonoBehaviour, which has the behaviour (heh) which I'm trying to recreate

Comment: Well, this is not unity ;). But, see it is giving you a way to achieve what you want, i think using `override` is more easy then implementing all the methods.

Comment: I am aware that C# does not equal Unity. But surely Unity must've accomplished it _somehow_ as I refuse to believe they used magic to remove the need for the override keyword.

Comment: @Basseyh that's where the difference comes into play. You are right that they didn't used any magic but they created it in this way but C# doesn't supports this. You have to use `override` its just what it is.

Comment: just like you have to use `{ }` in C# and other languages and not it python because its deigned that way obviously python dont use any magic its just how it is designed. Same thing here. I hope it clears you confusion.

Comment: @ZainArshad What? It's [written in C#](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference), and even that does not make any difference because when you consume a library, you do that according to the rules of the language you are consuming it from, not the language the library was written in.

Comment: @ZainArshad Unity doesn't use python, it uses C#. Which is also the language I'm using.

Comment: @GSerg and C++ also.

Comment: @Basseyh I did not say that its written in python I was just giving you an analogy.

Comment: @ZainArshad Please have a look at the [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). The OP asks how it is possible that `void Awake()`, `IEnumerator Start()` and `void Update()` are declared as is, without `override` or `partial`, and yet are recognized and called (all in C#).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a base class with for example Start() and a child class with Update() and Draw(). Depending on the case you inherit form base or a child of the base classe.

This should do the trick if the project is not too complex.

Comment: So no way to have `Update` without `Start`?

Comment: The problem here is, if I have a base class with Start, a child class with Update, child class of _that_ with Draw etc. is that I can't have a class inheriting only the Update and Draw functions for instance.